# Rodoviária, terminal ou terminal rodoviário?

Tags: português-brasileiro, diferenças

Costumo dizer "rodoviária", para me referir ao terminal rodoviário, o local de partida dos ônibus, mas às vezes me pego dizendo "terminal". Conhecidos e familiares meus costumam dizer "terminal", porém os mesmos dizem "rodoviária" de vez em quando.
Quando alguém comenta ou cita os banheiros de terminais rodoviários, sempre ouço "banheiro de rodoviária", e nunca "banheiro de terminal".

Há alguma diferença entre as três variações? Alguma delas é "mais errada"?

Comment: Só para que conste em Portugal diz-se "Central de camionagem".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todas são corretas e intercambiáveis.

- **estação rodoviária**
- **terminal rodoviário**
- **rodoviária**
- **terminal de autocarros**
- **terminal de ônibus**
- **e muitas outras variações.**

Acredito que se compararmos os termos usados em Cuiabá, Uruguaiana, Natal e Boa Vista, dificilmente ouviremos o mesmo termo duas vezes.